# Matrix calculation

Tags: c++, matrix, average

I have a large 2D matrix A2D, which the column rank and the row rank are always equal, and evenly divided by 4. I want to reduce both the column rank and the row rank to their respective quater (1/4) to form another matrix B2D. Each B2D element is an average of 4x4 sub-matrix of A2D. To account for clearly what I want to do, I take a simple 8x8 matrix for example, and provide the following code snippet for your reference. My solution is very clumsy. Would you please show me aother solution with better performance. Thank you in advance.

```
int arr[8][8] =     
{   
   {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}, 
   {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28},
   {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38},
   {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48},
   {51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58},
   {61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68},
   {71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78},
   {81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88}
};

int** pColAvg = new int* [8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    pColAvg[i] = new int[2];

for (int nRow = 0; nRow < 8; nRow + 4)
{   
    for (int nCol = 0; nCol < 8; nCol + 4)
    {  
        int Avg = 0;
        Avg += arr[nRow][nCol];
        Avg += arr[nRow][nCol + 1];
        Avg += arr[nRow][nCol + 2];
        Avg += arr[nRow][nCol + 3];
        Avg /= 4;

        pColAvg[nRow][nCol/4] = Avg;
    }
}

int** pAvgArray = new int* [2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pAvgArray[i] = new int[2];

for (int nRow = 0; nRow < 8; nRow + 4)
{    
    for (int nCol = 0; nCol < 2; nCol++)
    {   
        int Avg = 0;
        Avg += pColAvg[nRow][nCol];
        Avg += pColAvg[nRow + 1][nCol];
        Avg += pColAvg[nRow + 2][nCol];
        Avg += pColAvg[nRow + 3][nCol];
        Avg /= 4;

        pAvgArray[nRow/4][nCol] = Avg;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)     
    delete [] pColAvg[i]; 

delete [] pColAvg; 

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)     
    delete [] pAvgArray[i]; 

delete [] pAvgArray;
```

Comment: I suppose you mean the size and not the rank, as when speaking of matrices (which are always 2-dimensional, by the way) the rank means something different. Otherwise speak of 2-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your solution can be incorrect (even if by average you mean floor of exact average). Here is my solution:

```
int** solveIt(int **arr, int n){
    int **result = new int*[n/4];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=4){
        result[i] = new int[n/4];
        for(int j=0; j<n; j+=4){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
                for(int q=0; q<4; q++)
                    sum += arr[i+k][j+q];
            result[i/4][j/4] = sum/16;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

this is function that takes array and size of that array, and returns result array.

Edit:
and the example where your solution doesn't work:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
```

The answer is:

```
1
```

but your solution will give:

```
0
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure if your solution is right for me. My remote sensing instrument has for detectors. Each detector can scan 2500 lines at an time interval, and each scan line has 10000 pixels. User can combine the observations of 4 detectors to make a high resolution (10000x10000) image. On the other hand, user also can get a low resulotion (2500x2500) by averaging the four observations.

Comment: My condition is: I already have high resolution matrix. I want to derive another one with low resolution.